# Display number without decimal as is Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of numbers I want to display without the decimal, but excel either rounds or excludes zeros.

Example:

Text I have
1.75,
0.6,
0.60,
8.0,
45.0

What I want
175,
06,
060,
80,
450

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With your current data, you can use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0."&REPT(0,RIGHT(CELL("format",A1),1))),".","")
```

[image]

If you actually have text to begin with and not numbers, then just use `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")
```

[image]